# RxJS sort order on update going wrong in component

Tags: angular, sorting, rxjs

My State uses a custom sort:

```
export function sort(a: Item, b: Item): number {
    return a.isabstract === b.isabstract ? a.name.localeCompare(b.name) : a.isabstract ? 1 : -1;
}

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<Item> = createEntityAdapter<Item>({
    sortComparer: sort,
});
```

And then in my reducer I do an update:

```
on(ItemActions.getExtendedDataSuccess, (state, { data }) => {
    const update: UpdateStr<Item> = {
        id: data.itemid,
        changes: { extendeddata: data.extendeddata },
    };
    return adapter.updateOne(update, state);
}),
```

When the item is updated, I can see that the `sort` method is being called as expected.

In my component.ts, I have:

```
allitems: Array<Item>;
private items$: Observable<Dictionary<Item>> = this.coreSelectService.itemList$;

...

this.items$.pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive)).subscribe(i => {
    this.allitems = Object.values(i).filter(m => m.id !== "exclude");
});
```

And in my component.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of allitems">
    {{ item.name }}
</div>
```

On first load, the `item`s are in the correct order, ordered by name, with abstract items at the bottom of the list, like:

- A Item
- B Item
- Z Item
- Abstract Item

However, if I then trigger getExtendedDataSuccess on "A Item", the update occurs, the sort happens in the reducer, but in my component, the updated item goes to the bottom of the list, like:

- B Item
- Z Item
- Abstract Item
- A Item

It feels as if putting another sort in the component should be redundant, but I don't get why the order is being changed here?

Any tips please?

Comment: Have you tried supplying a value for the [key of each element](https://angular.io/api/core/TrackByFunction) in the ngFor?